# Saving another field value instead of id in drop down in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my view

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'p_28',
    CHtml::listData(AdCourt::model()->findAll(),'id','name') ,
    array(
        'class'=>'form-control',
        'style'=>'width:100%;',

        'empty'=>Yii::t('plaint','Суд турини танланг'),
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST', //request type
            'url'=>$this->createUrl('getcourts'),
            'update'=>'#ABlockForm_p_29',
        )
    )); ?>
```

`AdCourt` takes values from `ad_court` table. This tables consists of `id`, `name` and `court_id`. I need to save database `court_id` instead of `id`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of [`listData`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData) is the attribute of the items that will be used as the `value` for the `<option>` tag. As such to use the `court_id` instead of the `id` you should pass it instead:

```
CHtml::listData(AdCourt::model()->findAll(),'court_id','name')
```